# Moving data from T1 in Database D1 to T1 in Database D2

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases: D1 and D2.
D1 has Table `Basic_Details`; D2 also has a table `Basic_details`.  Both The  Basic_details tables have the same design.

`D1` has data. So how do I copy all the data from Table in D1 to the Table in D2?

Comment: Some databases will let you remotely connect to other databases.  Then it's an easy routine insert into d2.t1 select * from d1.t1.  What DB are you using?

Comment: Was tagged 'sql' and 'server', so I put 1 and 1 together.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you should be able to run
`INSERT INTO D2.Basic_details SELECT * FROM D1.Basic_details`
Note: if you table has identity field, you will need to enable identity inserts.

**Update**

`INSERT INTO D2.dbo.Basic_details SELECT * FROM D1.dbo.Basic_details`

or

`INSERT INTO D2..Basic_details SELECT * FROM D1..Basic_details`

Comment: @alex07: should i say 'use master' or use D1

Comment: That does not matter if you refer to the tables using [db_name].[table_name]. If you use `D1`, you don't have to write `...FROM D1.Basic_details`, it's enough just `... FROM Basic_details`. You still need to fully qualify another table ([db_name].[table_name]). Also, if you don't use default schema, you have to refer your tables as [db_name].[schem_name].[table_name]

Comment: @alex07: I did use D1.  insert into D2.Basic_details SELECT * FROM Basic_details. I gave me an error 'Invalid object name 'D2.Basic_details'.

Comment: Are D1 and D2 databases on the same server? In which schema is D2.Basic_details ?

Comment: @alex07: yes, both are on the same server. I did not change any schemas b4 creating D1, D2

Comment: My fault, you need to specify schema as well. Check if updated version works for you